# Pinning feet to walk in auto rig pro Blender 2.8

Tags: auto-rig-pro

I am using auto rig pro, it has the best weight paint read for rigging the mesh along with versatility of creating new bones that are converted into deforming rig bones without any bugs, in contrast to rigify. I am currently animating a pony. I would prefer to take the pony step by step and orient the entire objects movement around each step that is made. Meaning that I am trying to figure out how to constrain one foot down to plane or floor ground, then move the entire rig either from a guide in object mode or the universal mover in pose mode, while the foot is pinned down so that locomotion is generated into the meshes animation and overall location based upon a more realistic frame movement. To walk just as if a pony walks rather than having the foot slide back as the other pushes forward and then trick the objects locomotion to revolve around a hidden moon walk if you will. Any ideas on how to do this I would really appreciate it. I tried FreeIK, but it seems to only work for rigify bones and it really would drive up the scene with a bunch of functions that it brings in, even if it did work for auto rig pro. I also tried a locked track and track to constraint for the feet. Attempting to pin them to a empty object that would control the pivots of each step, but that did not work either.